# rsync excluding empty files

Tags: rsync

I recently discovered that a few files on a volume had been mysteriously truncated - or more accurately, replaced with a zero length file.

Fortunately, these files were hard-linked from multiple places, and only about half the links were actually overwritten with a zero-length file with seemingly the same attributes.

However, when I looked in my backups, I found the issue had occurred before my previous backup. For the volume in question, a simple mirror backup should be sufficient, because files shouldn't get deleted - it's mostly append only. But since the file isn't actually being deleted, I can't simply tell `rsync` to not delete.

Is there a way to tell `rsync` to not sync a file that is zero length locally, but has a non-zero length on the remote side?

I could of course simply write some code to look for zero length files and exclude them, but this is an extra time-consuming step (now there are two full scans of the filesystem) and it could exclude files which legitimately should be rsynced (in case there are files that are expected to be zero length).

Comment: You might want to look at `rsync`'s `--backup` options...

Comment: Also, it's not *possible* to have some of the hard links to a file be of a different size. All hard linked names are to the *same file*. If this isn't just a case of using the wrong term, and you actually have two hard links to the same file showing a different size—you have something very, very broken.

Comment: @derobert The hard links appears to have been replaced by zero length files which had the same file name and timestamp as the original file.

Answer (score 8):

`rsync` has a `--min-size` option:

```
 --min-size=SIZE         don't transfer any file smaller than SIZE
```

Thus `--min-size=1` suffices for neglecting empty files.

That should help you unless you have files that do have to be transferred if there is no zero byte sized file on the destination side of things.

AFAIK there is no way to tell rsync to take special action based on source and destination size.

Comment: And `SIZE` is in bytes? kilobytes? troglodytes? (Sorry, looked at the man page but couldn't find it there)

Comment: If you are to lazy to read the source, you can of course try and see what happens. It is bytes, but you can at least specify M for megabytes.

Comment: @Sixtyfive it's in the documentation, `man rsync`. If you look up `--min-size` you'll see it refers you to `--max-size`, where `SIZE` is defined

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned empty files, thus answer should me more specific, that is `--min-size=1`

Comment: This (`--min-size=1`) is extremely important for rsync mirror backups. I just lost some very important files and my double backup didn't help, exactly because those original files (due to a bug) instead of having been wiped out, were zeroed, i,.e, became empty. Although my mirror rsync backup didn't have the flag `--delete`, I lost all these files because the blank files eventually replaced the good files at the backup storage.

Answer (score 1):

NB: to avoid over-writing files with a zero length file, you'd need to set `--min-size=1`
It's not possible to have a file smaller than zero size.
Unless the man page is in error, and it should say "don't transfer any file smaller than or equal to SIZE"

Comment: This (`--min-size=1`) is extremely important for rsync mirror backups. I just lost some very important files and my double backup didn't help, exactly because those original files (due to a bug) instead of having been wiped out, were zeroed, i,.e, became empty. Although my mirror rsync backup didn't have the flag `--delete`, I lost all these files because the blank files eventually replaced the good files at the backup storage.